# DataTable server request on pagination

Tags: php, jquery, datatables, server-side

I am using data table for pagination,As it is client side so getting whole data(more than 50000) makes my page too busy and crash it.
Here is my code.what should I do?

```
$q="select * from table";
$rs = $oAppl->query($q);
<table class="display" id="example">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                   <th class="th_title">ID</th>
                   <th class="th_title"> Name</th>
                  </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <?php
             while ( $rw = $oAppl->row($rs) ) {
             ?>
                <tr class="item">
                    <td ><?php echo $rw["id"]; ?></td>
                   <td class="subject"><?php echo $rw["name"]; ?></td>
   </tr>
               <?php
               }
               ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
 $(document).ready(function() {
$('#example').dataTable();
 }
```

Comment: This plugin could work for ajaxifying your jquery datatable: http://blog.grio.com/2011/11/jquery-datatable-plugin-pagination.html

Answer (score 2):

Do NOT load that much of data to browser. Just make the user to do it. You can put page numbers, below the data block, which will be clicked by the user. If a user click the page 2, for example, call a `JQuery` function, which makes an `AJAX` call to the server and get second 10 (for example again) row from the table. You can divide the 50000 rows of data to any number of pages you want, and then load the `page_number*minimum_row_count` number of rows from server.

**Update**: (after the comment)

Unfortuantely, I cannot give you code sample right now, because I'm in a meeting ;) Datatables has a key `bServerSide` which basically tells the constructor "you're gonna fetch". And also by specifying `sAjaxSource`,`sServerMethod` and `iDisplayLength` in the initializer, you can set what you want. Here are some useful links. If you have any problem further, I can give code samples later in this evening ;)

[datatables server side stuff](http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/server_side/server_side.html)

[datatables custom variables](http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/server_side/custom_vars.html)

Comment: YES i know logic of pagination in PHP.i do not know how to do it in datatable ajax jquery etc etc..can you please give me complete example?